# Excel data type format when exporting datastore to Excel - Powerbuilder

Tags: excel, export, powerbuilder, datastore, cell-formatting

I'm exporting a datastore to excel and I can't export a string with the correct format. For example I have '594040100002640883' and in my excel cell is '5,9404E+17'.
When I click on the cell in the "Insert function" section is displayed "594040100002640000"
I tried to format the column using `excel.application.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).Columns(6).NumberFormat = "@"`, but I got the '5,9404E+17' as result.

How can I display the exactly string in the cell? I'm using ole objects.

Here is my code:

```
ids_dsdata.SaveAs(xls_path, HTMLTable!, True)

excel = CREATE OLEObject
li_rtn = excel.ConnectToNewObject("excel.application")
li_rtn = excel.ConnectToObject(xls_path)
if li_rtn = 0 then
    excel.application.DisplayAlerts = FALSE 
    
    excel.application.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).Range("C5").NumberFormat = "@"
    excel.application.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).Range("H5").NumberFormat = "00000"
    excel.application.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).Range("F5").NumberFormat = "00000"
    
    excel.application.workbooks(1).Parent.Windows(excel.application.workbooks(1).Name).Visible = True
    excel.application.workbooks(1).saveas(xls_path, 39)
    excel.application.workbooks(1).close()
else
    MessageBox("Error","OLE ConnectToObject return code = " +string(li_rtn),Exclamation!)
end if
DESTROY excel
```

Thanks!

Comment: Excel has a numeric precision of approximately sixteen digits.  So you need to **import** that data into Excel as text.  Don't **open** the file. How is the data exported from datastore?  If as a CSV file, then use Power Query or the Legacy import wizard to **import** into Excel, and designate that column as Text.  If datastore directly creates an excel file, then you will have to work within datastore so those values get created as text.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In datastore all the columns are strings. As matter of fact I save the datastoare as HTMLTable because of my table header and then I convert it in xls because of that cell data type format.

Comment: Maybe try exporting it as a CSV and then importing it into Excel. Or possibly try importing it into XL using power query on the HTML table. That might also allow designating that column as text. Once it gets into Excel the data has already been modified so the modification needs to be done beforehand.